Problem with slider value sending it to php
I have this slider:
<form id="sliderForm1" action="registerValidation.php" method="POST">
  <label for="sliderValue1">Kiek su tuo sutinkate?:</label>
  <output id="sliderOutput1" name="sliderOutput1">0</output>
  <input type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" id="sliderValue1" name="sliderValue1">
</form>

I have some javascript file, for checking lines, but its not essential here, there are no modification of values.
I try putting it to database:
$password_hash = password_hash($_POST["password"], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);


$mysqli = require __DIR__ . "/databaseConnect.php";


$sql = "INSERT INTO user (username, email, password_hash, slider1Value) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)"; //////////////!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!/////////////////////

try 
{
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param("sssi", $_POST["username"], $_POST["email"], $password_hash, $_POST["sliderValue1"]); //////////////////////////////////////////////
    $stmt->execute();
    header("Location: login.php");
    exit;
} 
catch (mysqli_sql_exception $exception) 
{
    if ($mysqli->errno === 1062) //dublicate key element error number
    {
        die("El. pašto adresas arba vartotojo vardas jau užimtas");
    } 
    else 
    {
        die("Klaida: " . $exception->getMessage());
    }
}

DB view:
Db view
But I keep getting an error: Column 'slider1Value' cannot be null.
I tried to change value manually, tried to give output values to $stmt.

Where are the username, email, and password inputs?

Do you have two different forms, one with those fields and the other with the slider? You need to put them in the same form.

Yes, i have 2 different forms, but i just cant put it in one place, in my quiz form i have slider, in registration form username and etc, maybe there is another solution?

If the slider can't be inside the <form> tag, give it a form="XXX" attribute, where XXX is the ID of the form with the username. That will link it to the form and its value will be sent when the form is submitted.

Look, i have 2 forms, for the slider and for the registration, i just cant understand, if i have action="registerValidation.php" and Method="Post" in slider form, i cant send it somehow without triggering any button?

You can only submit one of them at a time. If you submit the user form, it won't have the slider in it. If you submit the slider form, it won't have the user information.

You can split this into two different actions. First login with the user form. Then send the slider in a separate submission. The login form will set a session variable with the username. The script for the slider can then update the slider1Value for that user.

Thank you very much, the tag form="xxx" was an answer! You're the best.
